# JavaScript: what's the difference between a function name & function reference?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the Google Maps API and it states that the:

```
"callback: The function to call once the script has loaded. If using the Auto-loading feature, this must specify a function name, not a function reference.
```

What's the difference been a JavaScript function name vs a function reference?

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#GoogleLoad

Comment: Can you provide a link to exactly where that documenation fragment is?  Is it actually for the API itself, or is it for the Google javascript loader, or what? [edit] oh I found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function: `function func() {}`

function reference: `func`

function name: `'func'`

Answer (score 1):

A function name is a string (`"alert"`). A function reference is the function itself (`alert`).

Comment: so it would be *callback="function_name"* ?

Comment: If you're using auto-loading.

Comment: Yes, I'm using auto-loading. So is * callback="function_name"* correct?

Comment: If you're using auto-loading.

Comment: Any idea why *http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={modules:[{name:%22maps%22,version:3,{other_params:%22sensor=false%22,callback:%22function_name%22}]}* doesn't work then?

Answer (score 1):

The name of a function is a string such as 'foo' in this case:

```
function foo() {}
```

A reference to a function is any variable that is set to the value of the function itself (not the result of calling it).

Functions in Javascript can be [anonymous](http://helephant.com/2008/08/javascript-anonymous-functions/) - you can have a reference to a function that has no name.

```
var bar = function() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps what that bit of documentation means to say is that the "name" it expects should be a string containing the name of a function, instead of a "bare" function name (which *is* a reference to a function) or a function instantiation/definition expression.

*edit* OK I see what the deal is. This really isn't a Google Maps thing, it's the Google Javascript loader toolkit. The API does indeed want a string, which makes perfect sense since the function you want to call is *inside the code that you're loading*, and therefore you *can't* have a reference to it from the calling environment.

```
google.load("feeds", "1", {"callback" : "someFunctionName"});
```

It would make no sense to write:

```
google.load("feeds", "1", {"callback" : someFunctionName});
```

because "someFunctionName" used like that — as a reference to something — could not possibly be a reference to the right function (if it's defined at all).

Comment: so it would be *callback=function_name* or *callback=function_name()* ?

Comment: Neither: `{callback: "function_name"}`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.

```
// f1 :: function name
function f1(a) { return a*a; }  

// f2 :: reference to an anonymous function
var f2 = function(a) { return a*a; }  

// f3 :: a reference to the first function
var f3 = f1; 

// these are equivalent. The second one calls into 
// a different actual function. 
f1(3);  // 9
f2(4);  // 16
f3(5);  // 25
```

Comment: The question makes sense if you read the snippet of documentation in context.