# JavaScript: How do I use the "callback" function of the "autoload" feature of Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, callback

I am using Google Maps **v3**.

I'm currently using the autoload functionality and it's working great:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={modules:[{name:"maps",version:3,other_params:"sensor=false"}]}'></script>
```

Now I want to use the autoload to also include the `callback` option to callback my function named `myCallbackFunction()`.

How do I modify my working code above to include the `callback` option?

I've tried a few different ways and none work. I receive an "*Invalid Autoload*" error.

[The API is linked](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#GoogleLoad)

**UPDATE**:

I've tried the below, as well as a ton of other variations and none work. I still cannot figure out the appropriate syntax to use the `callback` method.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={modules:[{name:"maps",version:3,other_params:{"sensor=false","callback=myCallbackFunction"}]}'></script>
```

Comment: Can you post the other things that you have tried?

Comment: You just asked this question!!!

Comment: It would be so many, the listing would be massive. A quick and easy way to know if it works is to simply paste the code into a browser address bar and run it. The code above generates a lot of JavaScript, when I try adding in the parameter for a callback (since I don't know the syntax) I get an error

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: what's the difference between a function name & function reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813232/javascript-whats-the-difference-between-a-function-name-function-reference)

Comment: @Pointy, I found through reading the Google Maps API that it support natively a callback routine. My previous question today was now do I manually create a callback once the google map is loaded. It makes no sense for me to use my own method if the API supports it natively.

Comment: @Pointy, that's not a duplicate question. That's simply asking what's the difference between a function name & function reference. This current question is how to actually use the API.

Comment: @Pointy, regardless - I tried the following code and it still does not work:  *http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={modules:[{name:%22maps%22,version:3,{other_params:%22sensor=false%22,callback:%22function_name%22}]}*

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the Google AJAX loader and autoload?  They even mention in the documentation it should be used as a last resort: "This advanced feature can be difficult to implement, depending on the exact situation. Therefore, we recommend that auto-loading only be considered in specific cases when a reduction in latency is crucial."

You could just directly load the maps API asynchronously and specify a callback, a la the [answer to this FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#loadasync) and [example](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dynamicloading/scriptappend.html).

Answer (score 0):

The options that are supported by autoload for Google Maps are listed on [Google Loader Developer's Guide: Available APIs](https://developers.google.com/loader/#AvailableAPIs). The options listed under **supported options** are specified in the same manner as **name** or **version**.

For your example, the syntax would look like:

```
{
  "modules" : [
    {
      name : "maps",
      version : 3,
      callback : myCallbackFunction,
      other_params : "sensor=false"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or, formatted as a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules":[{name:"maps",version:3,callback:myCallbackFunction,other_params:"sensor=false"}]}'></script>
```